# How to disable visual studio update during the installation

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Visual Studio on a computer which doesn't have an internet connection. After running the `vs_setup` and after some minutes, I get an error that he couldn't download some installation files. That is rather odd because, the `vs_setup` has been run from an ISO image with more than 20GB!!

So, any thought on that?

[image]

Comment: You tagged your question "visual-studio-2010", but your screenshot shows the new VS logo, which was introduced with VS 2012. Please edit to indicate which version you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve this will depend on the version you use. This is for **Visual Studio 2017**.

To quote Microsoft, you're not really suppposed to install Visual Studio 2017 without an Internet connection:

> Visual Studio is primarily designed to be installed on an
>   internet-connected machine, since many components are updated
>   regularly. However, with some extra steps, it's possible to deploy
>   Visual Studio in an environment where a working internet connection is
>   unavailable.

*[Install certificates needed for Visual Studio offline installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline)*

However, there is a guide to install it off-line. It basically involves

- downloading the "Visual Studio bootstrapper"
- creating a local install cache ("layout") on a computer with an Internet connection
- moving the cache to the target computer, and run the installation there, using the cache

Microsoft provide detailed instructions:
[Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)